# Print post number in reverse order from thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, thymeleaf

```
<tbody>
                     <tr th:each="bean , beanStat : ${list}">
                            <td class="text-center" th:text="${beanStat.size-beanStat.count+1}+(${paging.cri.page}-1)*${cri.perPageNum}" >1</td>
                               <!--  paging.totalcount -->
                            
   <!--                  <tr th:each="bean , beanStat : ${list}">
                            <td class="text-center" th:text="${beanStat.size-beanStat.count+1}+(${paging.cri.page}-1)*${cri.perPageNum}" >1</td>
```

First of all, I'm sorry for not speaking English well.

I want to number the articles, but I want to number them in reverse order.
I think you can do it like below in jsp
In thymeleaf, I wonder how to do this in reverse order (is there an index?)

Total number of records - ( (Current page number - 1) * I think it is the number of records displayed per page.

${(totalCount - status.index) - ( (currentPage - 1) * displayNum ) }

I implemented it like this, but I wonder if there is such a part as status.index in the thymeleaf.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wL6Ps.png)

Comment: I wrote an answer but then I was not sure if it is what you want, so I deleted it. If you have `<tr th:each="item, iterStat : ${list}">` in your Thymeleaf template, then you can reverse the numbering using `<td th:text="${iterStat.size - iterStat.count +1}"></td>`. I see you are already aware of Thymeleaf's iteration status trackers, so maybe this is not what you need?

Comment: oh thanks for the reply. I'm not familiar with the thymeleaf, I didn't know there was such a thing as reverse iteration. so I'm sorry that I deleted the answer.  If it's okay with you, I' wnat to see the code before erasing. I'm sorry I'm not good at English

Comment: I un-deleted my answer. Take a look and see if it helps (or not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an equivalent to your JSP approach in Thymeleaf - a set of [iteration tracking](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#keeping-iteration-status) attributes you can use when processing a list.

Assuming you have a Java list like this:

```java
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("One");
list.add("Two");
list.add("Three");
```

Then you can use the following Thymeleaf:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Item</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each="item, iterStat : ${list}">
            <td th:text="${iterStat.size - iterStat.count +1}"></td>
            <td th:text="${item}"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This generates:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Item</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>One</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Two</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Three</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

**Update**

If you want to add paging into the calculation, then your Java code needs to know:

- current page number
- maximum number of rows per page (there may be fewer in the final page)
- total number of records (all pages)

Let's assume I pass those 3 values from Java to my Thymeleaf model with some new data:

```java
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("Alfa");
list.add("Bravo");
list.add("Charlie");
list.add("Delta");
list.add("Echo");

int currentPage = 1;
int rowsPerPage = 5;
int totalRecords = 9;
```

Now, the Thymeleaf changes to this:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Item</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each="item, iterStat : ${list}">
            <td th:text="${totalRecords - (currentPage * rowsPerPage)
                    + rowsPerPage - iterStat.count +1}"></td>
            <td th:text="${item}"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

For page 1 this generates:

```html
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>Alfa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>Bravo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>Charlie</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>Delta</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Echo</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

For page 2 (the final 4 items), we have:

```java
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("Foxtrot");
list.add("Golf");
list.add("Hotel");
list.add("India");

int currentPage = 2;
int rowsPerPage = 5;
int totalRecords = 9;
```

Note: Only the current page number has changed. The rows per page and the total records: those values remain the same across all pages.

And the same Thymeleaf template generates this:

```html
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Foxtrot</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Golf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Hotel</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>India</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: thank you It comes out well in reverse, but if you watch 10 rows per page.

If there are 18, I would like to number them from page 1 to 18 to 8, and from page 2 to 8 to 1.

Comment: I added an update to the answer to cover paging logic.